# return value of getregtype

Tags: vim

The simple way to select a pasted text is

```
`[v`]
```

The advanced way of doing it as given below.

```
nnoremap <expr> gb '`[' . strpart(getregtype(), 0, 1) . '`]'
" OR
nnoremap <expr> gb '`[' . getregtype()[0] . '`]'
```

What is the meaning of `strpart(getregtype(), 0, 1)` and `getregtype()[0]`?

Comment: `:%s/advanced/overly complicated`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, `getregtype()[0]` will visual select the text with your last visual selection mode, (char-wise, block-wise or line-wise).

The function `getregtype()` will return you :

```
v "for charwise
V "for linewise
^V{width} "for blockwise (ctrl-v)
```

take `[0]` or using wrapped `strpart()` function is just for getting the first byte.`v, V or ^V` so that your mapping will use the last visual selection mode to visual select the just pasted text.

```
:h getregtype(
```

For detail.

Similar trick is the usage of `setreg()` function, give the `{option}` to set mode.